# AngularStrap typeahead ng-options - different label than model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularStrap typeahead for some addresses. I would like to assign the selected address object to my ng-model but when I do so I lose the option to just show one of the object properties as the label.

Sample returned object:

```
{ formatted: '1001 Main St', geo: { lat: '123', lng: '234' } }
```

In view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.venue" ng-options="address as address.formatted for address in getLocation($viewValue)" placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
 Venue Object: {{ item.venue }}
```

I would have thought the above would work but it doesn't assign "formatted" as the label value - just blank after selection. Doing he following works but then it only assigns the formatted property to the model:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.venue" ng-options="address. address.formatted as address.formatted for address in getLocation($viewValue)" placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/30e63qea/1/

Comment: can you add a plunker/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that you want your input to be a `label` or `obj.label` of the selected obj, but want to maintain the selected information of the obj.

You can capture the $on selected event an add `.label`

```
  $scope.$on('$typeahead.select', function(v,i){
    console.log(v,i);
    $scope.selected.label =  $scope.selected.formatted_address;
  });
```

**Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/akYyjL1r4dNTuVUkb6iV?p=preview)**

Comment: Is there an easy way to differentiate each typeahead element when there are more than one of the same type? (i.e. they return the same objects). And are there docs on these events?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Looking through the source it appears that the AngularStrap typeahead is "label" aware. Meaning if an "label" object property is found it will use that.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/nur5oqqa/2/

So the object needs to be:

```
{ label: '1001 Main St', geo: { lat: '123', lng: '234' } }
```

And code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.venue" ng-options="address as address.label for address in getLocation($viewValue)" placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
```